# GROUP_CONCAT в JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица categories и таблица category_type со связью. Мне надо выбрать из таблицы categories категории и для каждой выбрать связи из category_type. 
Пробую так:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(category_type.type_id) as types
FROM `categories`
LEFT JOIN category_type on category_type.category_id = categories.id
```

но в результате возвращает только те строки у которых есть связь в таблице category_type

Comment: Без группировки запрос вернёт хрень...

Answer (score -2):

Магия

```
SELECT categories.*, GROUP_CONCAT(category_type.type_id) as types
FROM `categories`
LEFT JOIN category_type on category_type.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.id
```

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, в чём была проблема и почему этот код решает её.

Comment: Проблема описана в вопросе: "в результате возвращает только те строки у которых есть связь в таблице category_type". Прежде чем писать комментарий может будете читать вопрос?